# complete the series(data frame) in python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

I have data set like this. I want to fill this data frame like described in output. Basically the missing series values will be filled as zero

```
 Date Opened     Part Number  NCe
0   2019-01-14    partA       1
1   2019-01-21    PartB       2
2   2019-01-21    PartC       1
3   2019-01-28    PartB       3
```

Output:

```
  Date Opened    Part Number  NCe
 2019-01-14      partA       1
 2019-01-14      PartB       0
 2019-01-14      PartC       0
 2019-01-21      PartA       0
 2019-01-21      PartB       2
 2019-01-21      PartC       1
 2019-01-28      PartA       0
 2019-01-28      PartB       3
 2019-01-28      PartC       0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your original dataframe is `df`, you should first use `crosstab` and `reset_index` to build the full list of expected lines:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.crosstab(df['Date Opened'], df['Part Number']
                    ).stack()).reset_index()[['Date Opened', 'Part Number']]
```

it gives:

```
  Date Opened Part Number
0  2019-01-14       PartB
1  2019-01-14       PartC
2  2019-01-14       partA
3  2019-01-21       PartB
4  2019-01-21       PartC
5  2019-01-21       partA
6  2019-01-28       PartB
7  2019-01-28       PartC
8  2019-01-28       partA
```

It is not correctly ordered because lower case `p` comes after upper `P` in collating sequence. You can fix it by sorting using the last character of Part Number:

```
df2 = df2.assign(ix=df2['Part Number'].str[-1]).sort_values(['Date Opened', 'ix']
                               )[['Date Opened', 'Part Number']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

You can now merge the original values, fill missing ones with 0 and cast back to int:

```
df2.merge(df, how='left', on = ['Date Opened', 'Part Number']).fillna(0).astype({'NCe': int})
```

to get:

```
  Date Opened Part Number  NCe
0  2019-01-14       partA    1
1  2019-01-14       PartB    0
2  2019-01-14       PartC    0
3  2019-01-21       partA    0
4  2019-01-21       PartB    2
5  2019-01-21       PartC    1
6  2019-01-28       partA    0
7  2019-01-28       PartB    3
8  2019-01-28       PartC    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have defined your dataframe in variable named 'df', you can check below if it helps:-

1. First I created an skeleton dataframe combining all the elements from your two columns of your dataframe.
2. Next I simply joined these dataframes in the order that the skeleton dataframe forms the base of your final output. Simply fill the NaN values with '0' using .fillna().

   `dates = df.Date_Opened.unique().tolist()`

   `parts = df.Part_Number.unique().tolist()`

   `index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, parts], names = ["Date_Opened", "Part_Number"])`

   `skeleton_df = pd.DataFrame(index = index).reset_index()`

   `final_df = pd.merge(skeleton_df, df, on=['Date_Opened','Part_Number'], how ='left').fillna(0)`

Output

```
  Date_Opened Part_Number  NCe
0  2019-01-14       partA  1.0
1  2019-01-14       PartB  0.0
2  2019-01-14       PartC  0.0
3  2019-01-21       partA  0.0
4  2019-01-21       PartB  2.0
5  2019-01-21       PartC  1.0
6  2019-01-28       partA  0.0
7  2019-01-28       PartB  3.0
8  2019-01-28       PartC  0.0
```

Note:- There are definitely better ways to solve, I will post an update as I could test another.

Comment: while doing merge, it throws error: You are trying to merge on int64 and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: I guess either of the date columns in your dataframe is string while the other is datetime. Try Converting your datetime column to string format.